# Restify and Angular JS both are on different domain how can i set httponly cookie using restify response?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, cookies, restify

I am using REST architecture for a web application created in Restifyjs and Frontend of this is in Angular JS both are running on different domains. For example on my local restify is working on `locahost:7000` and angular js is working on `localhost:5000.`

I am calling the Login API from frontend and authenticate the user from restify server and sending a token which needs to be set in cookies so i am using this but its not working any idea why ?

```
res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', 'mycookie=test;expires=Fri, 13 Jun 2017 02:34:20 GMT;domain=localhost;path=/');
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Is the cookie not being set?

Comment: @HeadCode yeah API's created by Restify returning cookies but its not getting set in Browser.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing more code, but my guess is that you have already sent body content to the browser before your setHeader gets called.  Is that possible?  Setting the cookie must take place before anything else.